# Address of site

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

My question is related to the address of the site i've created.

Currently the address is

```
http://server/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/
```

Is this ok to use, or should it be something tidier? Is it possible to have something like the following?

```
http://server/start.aspx#/
```

Maybe in the great scheme of things it won't matter? 
I'm using SharePoint Foundation 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. You can try browse http://server/ and it will redirect to http://server/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/.

When you need the address to run sometimes (e.g. Connect with SharePoint Designer, run a PowerShell command, or send the URL to some user) always use `http://server/`, not `http://server/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/` or `http://server/start.aspx#/`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want _layouts/15/start.aspx to be a part of your URL you need to deactivate Minimal Download Strategy feature available under Site Actions -> Manager Site Features

Comment: You should point out the impact of turning off MDS. It will increase page load times.

Comment: 0.01 ms vs 0.009 ms

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes because of the [Minimal Download Strategy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456544.aspx) feature. MDS (new in SP2013, and activated by default on every Team Site) is a real pain the ass. You can deactivate it on a per-site basis ("Site settings", "Manage Site Features" and disable "Minimal Download Strategy").